# biblatex: title and authors to be switched and followed by a line break instead of punctuation

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

The following MWE explains what I'd like to obtain:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{            knuth1984,
  edition       = {1},
  title         = {The TeXbook},
  isbn          = {9780201134483},
  publisher     = {Addison Wesley},
  author        = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  date          = {1984-01-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\fullcite{knuth1984}| gives:\par
  \fullcite{knuth1984}
\item I'd like to give:

  \citetitle{knuth1984}\\
  Donald E. Knuth\\
  1st ed. Addison Wesley, Jan. 1, 1984. \textsc{isbn}: 9780201134483
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Namely, I'd like `\fullcite` to:

- switch title and authors: though I can achieve this by redefining the whole `\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}`, I'd like to achieve the same result with `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibdriver` and all my attempts failed,
- replace the punctuation after the title and the author by a line break. With `\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\newline}`, I'm able to replace *all* the units punctuations by a line break but I'd like this only for title and authors.

For the latter point, all my attempts to `\newbibmacro*` `title`, `maintitle+title`, etc. failed, for instance:

```
\xpatchbibmacro{maintitle+title}{%
  \newunit
}{%
  \setunit{\par\nobreak}
}{success}{failure}
%
\xpatchbibmacro{title}{%
  \newunit
}{%
  \setunit{\par\nobreak}
}{success}{failure}
```

Hence my question: how could I patch `biblatex`'s default style in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Should tthe result be attained only for a fullcite, or also in the bibliography itself?

Comment: @Bernard Only for a `\fullcite`. It is for a very special (part of a) document, a books review: for each book, its reference will be typeset in a fancier way than usually and will be followed by the review. Hence, no need of a list of references (usual bibliography).

Comment: So whether it affects the list of references or not has no importance?

Comment: @Bernard Locally to a `refsection`, no.

Comment: @Bernard BTW, if it is simpler to deal with the list of references, I could manage. But, as the default style for the whole document is `numeric`, the point would be to not display neither the references numbers not their square brackets.

Comment: I've done it, butI've got a problem: usually, when I want to patch

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20895/discussion-between-bernard-and-denis-bitouze).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
%
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
 \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
 \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
 \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
 \newunit
 }
 {%
 \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}
 \newline\nopunct\newblock
 \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
 \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
 }{}{}


 \xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
 \newunit\newblock
 \printfield{edition}%
 }{%
 \newline\nopunct\newblock
 \printfield{edition}%
 }{}{}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{ knuth1984,
 edition = {1},
  title = {The TeXbook},
  isbn = {9780201134483},
  publisher = {Addison Wesley},
  author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  date = {1984-01-01}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \verb|\fullcite{knuth1984}| gives:\par
  \fullcite{knuth1984}
\item I'd like to give:

  \citetitle{knuth1984}\\
  Donald E. Knuth\\
  1st ed. Addison Wesley, Jan. 1, 1984. \textsc{isbn}: 9780201134483
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, nice: what I was missing is the patch `\newunit\newblock` → `\setunit{\newline}`. If I understand well, in the case the `edition` field is empty, this doesn't work anymore and one has to patch `\newunit\newblock\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}`, etc. Instead of patching all the following units/blocks, is it possible to patch only the `maintitle+title` and `author/editor+others/translator+others` units/blocks?

Comment: I'll try to see that.

Comment: @Denis Bitouzé: I've modified my code. Seems to work fine now, with and without the `edition` field.