# biblatex: how to plagiarize a (book) entry type?

Tags: biblatex, xpatch

I'd like to provide a `biblatex`'s entry type, `bookreview`, similar to the `book` one with the following differences:

- it supports an additional `type=list,datatype=name` field, `reviewer` (for the book's reviewer),
- some of its fields are reordered and formatted differently.

For this I can create a custom data model containing:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{bookreview}{%
 〈almost the same as for the `book` driver〉
}
%
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{reviewer}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[bookreview]{reviewer}
```

I guess the last two commands are necessary, but I wonder if there is a more clever way to plagiarize a (`book`) entry type that lets me avoid to almost completely copy the `book` driver and lets me just use `xpatch`'s `\xpatchbibdriver` (as asked by me in [biblatex: title and authors to be switched and followed by a line break instead of punctuation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226843/18401)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Biber you can use the fields `related` and `relatedtype` and it creates an entry with reference to the reviewed item (see section 3.4, Related Entries in the Biblatex manual).

For example, the article `michael1992` refers to `owens1986a` as a review of it.

```
@article{test1992a,
    Author = {Test, John},
    Journal = {test journal},
    Related = {owens1986a},
    Relatedtype = {reviewof},
    Title = {TEST case review},
    Year = {1992}}

@article{owens1986a,
    Author = {Owens, Joseph},
    Journal = {Dialogue: Canadian Philosophical Review/Revue canadienne de philosophie},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {697--708},
    Title = {Is There Any Ontology in Aristotle?},
    Volume = {25},
    Year = {1986}}
```

If you just want the reviewers name, try adding it in the field `byreviewer` to the original item.

Comment: (I'm very sorry for the delay: I was (too) busy.) I completely agree it would be more consistent for the review to be stored in another reference, since it is not part of the original book. And I didn't know the `Related` field, which is exactly what I was looking for.